# Sql Server Replication Slow when Downloading to Publisher

Tags: sql-server, replication

I got a very weird problem.

On a SQL Server 2017 Standard and with MERGE replication with job run at subscriber.

The problem happens in 2 out of 4 of our customers environment.

The configuration is as follows:

1 Publisher - 3 subscriber

In 2 of the customers, we have the following situation:

Pushing from Publisher to Subscriber ---> Extremely fast, about 150 rows per second, rated "excellent"

Pushing from Subscriber to Publisher ---> Extremely slow, max 2 rows per second.

We went to a lot of troubleshooting without finding any possible explanation.

The internet connection is extremely fast, with a latency of 25ms and upload/download around 50Mbits, so I think we can exclude network problems (in fact, we can push data to subscriber very fast).

We thought it could be a trigger problem. At publisher there are more triggers.. so  we disable all of them, we also tried different tables, just to exclude it was a problem related to only one table.. nothing... still very slow.

We thought it could be a problem of slow disk speed or privileges, so I have tried granting volume maintenance to MSSQL service users, nothing.

[image]

Disk speed is great, it's a SSD server grade.

We really don't know what it could be.

This is a screenshot where you can see pushing is way faster than download (from publisher perspective). 30k rows in 4 minutes pushed. 3 minutes for 400 download.

[image]

Does anyone have some ideas? This is happening only for 2 out of 4 scenarios. It's the same database.

The fast "sites" have a 50gb database. The 2 slow one are actually smaller database. Like 20k rows in a table.

Did check tables like:
mslogreader_history, MSRepl_Commands... etc and everything appear to be normal and clean.

Comment: This is Merge Replication you're using, or what kind?

Comment: Also tag with your version of SQL Server

Comment: yes merge replication sorry. I should have put it. SQL Server 2017. I updated my question.